# JNI folder is not picked up by Android studio after headers are generated

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am working on building an Android Library which is part of a larger Android app project. I am using Android Studio.

I created the Android library as a module in the Android app project. I created my native methods, and then I put the .class through javah -jni and I was able to see the jni folder created and the header file generated.

However, Android Studio is not picking up the jni folder and showing it in the project view.

Anybody have any idea, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of looking through docs, and posts, and tutorials, I remembered to check the simplest of things. **Make sure your jni folder is in src/main**